# trouble with moving data from PostgreSQL to Vertica

Tags: postgresql, csv, vertica

I want to move some tables from PostgreSQL to Vertica, but having trouble with saving column's types as they were. After moving table to Vertica all my columns' types are `VARCHAR`. To copy table from PostgreSQL I use

```
SET DATESTYLE TO 'ISO';
COPY (select * from table_name) TO '/tmp/file_name.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

To copy table to Vertica I use:

```
SET DATESTYLE TO 'ISO';
CREATE FLEX TABLE M.TABLE_NAME();
COPY M.TABLE_NAME FROM '/tmp/file_name.csv' PARSER FDELIMITEDPARSER (delimiter=',');
SELECT COMPUTE_FLEXTABLE_KEYS('M.TABLE_NAME');
SELECT COMPUTE_FLEXTABLE_KEYS_AND_BUILD_VIEW('M.TABLE_NAME');
CREATE TABLE M.TABLE_NAME_NORMAL_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM M.TABLE_NAME_view;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Is there a particular reason you're using Flex instead of a regular table?

Comment: As I said I have problem with column types I want them to be as in PostgreSQL, because now I have only varchar type for all my data. Using Flex I don't need column definition.

Comment: I'm still not clear. You want Vertica to determine the appropriate data types? Because it won't past `VARCHAR` and `INT`.